# AngularJS, resolve is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Что-то не могу понять, в чем проблема. Есть вот такой простой кусок код:

```
return $q(function load(resolve, reject) {
    var source = nextSource();
    var api = getById(source.resourceId);
    if (!loadedSources[index]) {
        api.promiseLoadContentPart(source).then(function(result) {
            if (result == 'error') {
                reject(false);
            } else if (result == 'loaded' || callbackStopLoading()) {
                loadedSources[index] = true;
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                load();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

И он работает как надо, пока дело не доходит до

```
resolve(true);
```

Который валится с такой ошибкой:

> angular.js:13920 TypeError: resolve is not a function

Собственно, в чем проблема?

Comment: `load();` - вызывается без параметров. следовательно внутри вызова _resolve_ и _reject_ будут _undefined_

Comment: _Есть вот такой простой кусок код:_ - код далеко не простой, с рекурсивными promise еще разобраться надо

Comment: @Grundy, точно, спасибо, как я мог не заметить такую ошибку...